# How to install google apps when android built from source

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I added a kernel module to the msm flo kernel. I built android JB from source for my Nexus 7(flo). I flashed the device with the built OS. I can add 3rd party apps for which I have apks or I could add them to the source tree.

But I can't add google apps or anything from the play store. I can't add my google account under settings->add accounts since it doesn't exist. I tried installing google play store by downloading the apk to my machine and installing it with apk. Play store does install, but play store crashes as soon as I click on it.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you asking for the proper (and legal) method of getting Google Applications on your device, or a workaround to avoid Google's Mobile Application Distribution Agreement? In either case, this does not sound like a question about a programming issue, but rather an issue with how to install someone else's software, and thus off topic for SO.

Comment: I am asking a legal method of getting google applications. It might be a programming question because it might be related to building the source tree

Comment: It is not. Google applications and Android, though unified in most consumer's minds, are in fact separate. Some custom Android distribution communities (such as XDA developers) frequently share archives of the latest Google apps suite, though if you intend to distribute your build with those apps, you will likely need to contact Google to explore how to do it the official and "correct" way.